# How to add custom product attribute?

Tags: magento2, product, attributes

I want to add custom attribute in product that have dropdown and can be sorted and filtered?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to catalog product and edit any product

[image]

step 1: click add attribute button.

step 2: provide name and properties to the attribute.

step 3: save and check your product grid it will show you your custom attribute

if need to edit this attribute go to **Store->attributes->product** serach for the attribute and edit it